# Valid MSSQL query returning no rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, php-7

I'm trying to learn PHP in my spare time and using a front-end for an internal MS SQL DB we've got as a quick learning project.  I've got a query prepped, but it never returns any rows.  I've validated that executing the query as the connection user returns the expected 26 results (via both Powershell and SSMS) and am able to pull and display last backup jobs for each DB in a php script so rights, driver, and query are all ruled out.  Trying `sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)` or `sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)` both return as false (as expected when no rows are present).  Am I perhaps over-looking something extremely simple?

Code

```
$ConnectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"NetworkInfo", "UID"=>$UID, "PWD"=>$PWD);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $Instance, $ConnectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established to $Instance. <br />";
}
else{
    echo "Connection could not be established. <br />";
    print_r($ConnectionInfo);
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
echo '<br />';

$SQL_String= "USE NetworkInfo
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.site.name AS Site,
                dbo.site.colloquial_name AS 'Colloquial Name',
                dbo.site.former_name AS 'Former Name',
                dbo.hrlocation.location_datis AS 'HR Site',
                dbo.site.address AS Address,
                dbo.site.city AS City,
                dbo.site.state AS State,
                dbo.site.zip AS ZIP,
                dbo.site.main_line AS 'Main Line',
                dbo.site.main_ext AS 'Main Ext'
FROM dbo.site
JOIN dbo.hrlocation ON dbo.site.id = dbo.hrlocation.site_id";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $SQL_String);  
echo '<h3>$stmt</h3>';
echo 'Var_dump:';
$dump = var_dump($stmt);
echo '<br />';
if( $stmt === false ) {  
    echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  
else {
    echo 'Returned type: ' . gettype($stmt) . '<br />';
    echo 'Returned rows: True' . sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) . '<br />';
    echo 'Number of rows: ' . sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt) . '<br />'; 
}
```

Output

```
Connection established to server. 

$stmt
Var_dump:resource(3) of type (SQL Server Statement) 
Returned type: resource
Returned # rows:
```

Comment: Can you please try a simpler query like this, also while there read the Note section about handling multiple results http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php

Comment: It's a simple output formatting query, and simplifying doesn't change the result.

The mssql_ functions were deprecated in PHP7.0.0, although the note you mentioned is not present in the [replacement function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) or [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-2017), though using the replacement function does allow me to view the first expected row.  Why is it though that I'm unable to get a count of the total returned rows, which is where I was believing myself to be stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is actually two-fold.

First, the use of SQL `USE` was causing an issue, however I'm still unsure as to why.  Removing `USE NetworkInfo` from the query returns expected results.

Secondly, the docs for sqlsrv_num_rows() clearly states the statement resource needs to be created with a static or keyset cursor.  Adjusting the resource creation to `$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $SQL_String, array(), array("Scrollable"=>'keyset'));` resolves the issue.